# Flutter | use the same widget multiple times with different state

Tags: flutter, widget, state-management

Salam, I'm a flutter developer, and I have in my application a **TabBar**, and in the **TabBarView** I have multiple widgets, these widgets count depends on a list, I loop the list and generate a widget each time, (it is the same widget) which means I use the same widget multiple times in the **TabBarView** but with different values I passed to it from the list I have, and it is a stateful widget

I need a very specific behavior, which I can't reach

**the required behavior is:**

when I enter the screen that contains the TabBar, I need the first Tab Item to be selected, thereby the first Tab Bar View Item to be built (calling the initState of it), and once I switch between the tabs, asume I selected the second tab item, I need the second Tab View Item to be built as the first one (calling the initState of it) and at the same time I need to keep the first one state alive (I don't want dispose() to be called), I want the dispose() to be invoked only when I get out from the entire screen only.

the actual behavior:

when I enter the screen that contains the TabBar, the first Tab Item is selected, thereby the first Tab Bar View Item is built and the initState() of it is called, but when I click on the second Tab Bar Item, the second Tab Bar View item is built, but initState() is not called again.

according to the actual behavior, I think that since I'm using the same widget multiple times at the same time, it seems they have same state, is that true? it is just my theory, and what should I do in order to achieve the required behavior?? I need a solution even if required me to change the whole context of the screen

Comment: Could you show us the code for the `TabBarView` you're using?

Comment: That's what a riverpod family is for

Comment: Instead of using TabBarView you can use PageView with PageController. This allows you to have more control over the lifecycle of each page.